# PHP - how can i save the information from the textbox when i submit the button?

Tags: php

I'm building a small script, when i click at the button, the script add one more textbox automatically.

My script is working really well, but when i submit the button, it clear all the textboxes, how can i change that, saving all the textbox information when i submit?

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--

$(document).ready(function(){

    var counter = 2;
    $("#add").click(function () {
        if(counter==11){
            alert("Too many boxes");
            return false;
        }   
        $("#textBoxes").html($("#textBoxes").html() + "<div id='d"+counter+"' ><label for='t2'> Textbox "+counter+"</label><input type='textbox' id='t"+counter+"' > </div>\n");
        ++counter;
    });

    $("#remove").click(function () {
        if(counter==1){
            alert("Can u see any boxes");
            return false;
        }   
        --counter;
        $("#d"+counter).remove();
    });
});

// -->
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id='textBoxes'>
    <div id='d1'>
        <label for="t1">Textbox 1</label>
        <input type='textbox' id='t1' />
    </div>
</div>
<input type='button' value='add' id='add' />
<input type='button' value='remove' id='remove' />
```

Comment: You are importing jquery 2 times ...

Comment: Where is your submit code?

Comment: My submit code is here "<input type='button' value='add' id='add'>
<input type='button' value='remove' id='remove'>"

Comment: So when you add another textbox the original text box loses it's value? Or the new textbox doesn't have any value? Change the .html to .append

Comment: Yea, loses it's value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="textbox" name="textbox[]">
<input type="textbox" name="textbox[]">
<input type="textbox" name="textbox[]">
<input type="textbox" name="textbox[]">
<input type="textbox" name="textbox[]">

<?php

if( isset( $_REQUEST['textbox'] ) )
{
    foreach( $_REQUEST['textbox'] as $textbox )
    {
        // $textbox contains the input's text.
    }
}

?>
```

EDIT : And jQuery provides a function .clone() that you could (should) use.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use the 'name' property in your input.
But what's append when you submit ? Is there a redirection to an other page ? Or do you want to stay on this page and show a message of confirmation ? In this case you could use Ajax to submit your form

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    var counter = 2;
    $("#add").click(function () {
        if (counter==11) {
            alert("Too many boxes");
            return false;
        }   
        $("#textBoxes").append('<div id="d'+counter+'"><label for="'+counter+'"> Textbox "'+counter+'"</label><input type="textbox" id="t'+counter+"' ></div>\n");
        ++counter;
    });

    $("#remove").click(function () {
        if (counter == 1) {
            alert("Can u see any boxes");
            return false;
        }   
        --counter;
        $("#d"+counter).remove();
    });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <div id='textBoxes'>
            <div id='d1'>
                <label for="t1">Textbox 1</label>
                <input type='textbox' id='t1'>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type='button' value='add' id='add' />
        <input type='button' value='remove' id='remove' />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```